# Cannot access the NextAuth session data in Next.js 12 middleware

Tags: javascript, next.js, middleware

I am trying to implement route protection using the new Next.js 12 middleware function. But it occurs to me that every time I try to access the session I get null. Hence not getting the expected result. Why is that?

```
import { NextResponse, NextRequest } from 'next/server'
import { getSession } from "next-auth/react"

//This acts like a middleware, will run every time for pages under /dashboard, also runs for the nested pages
const redirectUnauthenticatedUserMiddleware = async (req, ev) => {
     const session = await getSession({ req })
     if (!session) {
         return NextResponse.redirect('/login')
     }
    return NextResponse.next()
}

export default redirectUnauthenticatedUserMiddleware
```

Comment: I had a similar issue, maybe this question I raised would help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67234794/nextjs-and-nextauth-session-user-object-getting-lost-due-to-nextauth-ts-get

Comment: any updates regarding this matter?

Answer (score 8):

There's another ways on how you can get access to your `session`.

Here we're using `getToken` from `next-auth/jwt`.
**to note**:

- must **use** or **declared** `secret` as an `option` in `NextAuth` `function` (related reference [here](https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/options#secret)). If not, it will not work. Doesn't matter if you use `session` or `jwt` `option`. Both will work.

```
export default NextAuth({
  secret: process.env.SECRET,
  ...otherOptions
})
```

- currently I don't know whether it will work or not if you don't use token. Or you use database option only. Or adapter. I'm not sure since currently I'm unable to make adapter work just yet. So that's that.

Here is an example `_middleware.js`:-

```
import { getToken } from 'next-auth/jwt';
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';

export async function middleware(req, ev) {
  // 'secret' should be the same 'process.env.SECRET' use in NextAuth function
  const session = await getToken({ req: req, secret: process.env.SECRET }); console.log('session in middleware: ', session)

  if(!session) return NextResponse.redirect('/')
  
  return NextResponse.next()
}
```

If you already found a solution on how to make use `getSession`. You may upload your answer and share with us. Thank you.

Comment: const session = await getSession({ req: req, secret: process.env.SECRET });
    console.log('session in middleware: ', session)

Is not working for me.

Comment: unfortunately we can't use `getSession()` here in `middleware` as of now @JulianWagner. You can use `getToken()` to get your session.

Answer (score 2):

The above answer is correct and working, for those who are wondering.
useSession and getSession only work on the client side but the application of middleware in nextjs is on the server side so using these two won't work or probably throw an error. consider using getToken. also secret you pass to getToken is your self-created secret usually named **NEXTAUTH_SECRET** in env